# PermissionError when trying to load the layers in an ESRI File Geodatabase

Tags: python, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, fiona

I am trying to list the layers of a file geodatabase using `fiona`. I would like to then pick a layer and use `geopandas` to extract the layer as a geodataframe:

```
import fiona

layers = fiona.listlayers(r'main_datasets/BRT/TOP10NL.gdb')
```

I get an error as follows:

> fiona.errors.DriverError: Permission denied

I did the following:

- Removed any .lock files which exist within the gdb
- Tried opening other gdbs to see if I got the same error

Removing lock files in this particular gdb did not help. Strangely, the method in `fiona` successfully lists layers in other gdbs which don't have any notable differences (I checked in ArcCatalog and these are also FileGDB's as far as I can tell).

Why is this particular gdb giving me trouble? What could be causing the permission error?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. That particular gdb contains .cdf files which means it is compressed. OGR cannot handle compressed gdbs. I had to uncompress the geodatabase using ArcMap first and was then able to read it using Fiona.